# How to move datagridview rows up or down based on a button click

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, datagridview

I have DataGridView which is bounded with a datatable. I fill this datatable from database. I have 2 buttons right next to the datagridview, Up and Down. the rows should move up and down based on whichever button i click. I understand there are many answers for the similar issues but they work if your gridview isnt bounded. I also have a sequence column which has numbers from 0 onwards. When the rows move up or down, the sequence should be fixed as well. For example, if i move row[12] up, the sequence of row[12] should update to row[11] and row[11] should move down and row[11] sequence becomes row[12]. (I'm sorry if this is confusing). I also have 2 event functions attached to up and down buttons as well.

**Edit**: The main goal of this gridview is that user can add new rows as well. So, along with the above information, if there are 5 rows with sequence 1 to 5, and the user adds another row with sequence 2. I can sort the rows but how do I make the origninal rows with sequence 2,3,4,5 shift down and change their sequence to 3,4,5,6?

```
private void moveRow(int position)
    {
        DataRow selectedDataRow = null;
        DataRow newDataRow = null;
        int sequence = -1;
        int newSequence = -1;
        DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0];
        sequence = (int)selectedRow.Cells[sequenceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Index].Value;
        newSequence = sequence + position;
        if (newSequence <= 0 || newSequence > dataGridView.Rows.Count)
        {
            return;
        }



        //below code doesnt work at all maybe cuz it isnt right
        //How do i select the current row and the row at the new sequence?????



            if (selectedDataRow != null && newDataRow != null)
            {//below i try to assign sequences to the rows
                selectedDataRow["Sequence"] = newSequence;
                newDataRow["Sequence"] = sequence;
            }
            dataGridViewRed.Sort(dataGridViewRed.Columns[buildSequenceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Index], ListSortDirection.Ascending);// i sort it again based on sequence
            dataGridViewRed.CurrentCell = dataGridViewRed.Rows[selectedRow.Index + position].Cells[buildSequenceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Index];//highlight the current selected cell
//below functions are the events attached to the buttons for up and down
private void UpBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        moveRow(-1);
    }

    private void DownBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        moveRow(+1);
    }
```

There are definitely some loopholes in my explanation so please be kind. I will do my best to explain any confusions, if need be.

Comment: Why not sort by the the sequence value(s) and just maintain that rather than trying to manage rows in a *bound* control?

Comment: let me edit my question. i forgot a major point. Sorry.

Comment: When they add, loop thru the datasource and update the IDs which are 2 or above.  If you are using the proper collection type the DGV will (re)sort itself.  You arent supposed to try to manage DGV rows in a bound control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your rows are bound, then following example is applicable for moving row up. Prober Bounding should take care about sorting the `DataGridView` on the screen. If you sorted it in the data bound source, then it should work without `.Sort`, I think (I didn't test that).

If the row numbering could be inconsistent (c#):

```
DataGridViewRow SelectedDataRow = ...;
if (SelectedDataRow.Index > 0)
{
    DataGridViewRow PrevDataRow = DataGridView1.Rows(SelectedDataRow.Index - 1);
    Int16 PrevSequence = PrevDataRow.Cells("Sequence").Value;  // buffer the previous sequence
    PrevDataRow.Cells("Sequence").Value = SelectedDataRow.Cells("Sequence").Value;    // set previous sequence to selected
    SelectedDataRow.Cells("Sequence").Value = PrevSequence;                           // set selected to previous
}
```

VB.NET:

```
        Dim SelectedDataRow As DataGridViewRow = ...
        If SelectedDataRow.Index > 0 Then
            Dim PrevDataRow As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(SelectedDataRow.Index - 1)
            Dim PrevSequence As Int16 = PrevDataRow.Cells("Sequence").Value  ' buffer the previous sequence
            PrevDataRow.Cells("Sequence").Value = SelectedDataRow.Cells("Sequence").Value    ' set previous sequence to selected
            SelectedDataRow.Cells("Sequence").Value = PrevSequence                           ' set selected to previous
        End If
```

If the rownumbering is consistent (continuous 1 to N), then it can be simplified:

```
DataGridViewRow SelectedDataRow = ...;
if (SelectedDataRow.Index > 0)
{
    DataGridViewRow PrevDataRow = DataGridView1.Rows(SelectedDataRow.Index - 1);
    PrevDataRow.Cells("Sequence").Value = SelectedDataRow.Index + 1;
    SelectedDataRow.Cells("Sequence").Value = SelectedDataRow.Index;                            // set selected to previous
}
```

VB.NET:

```
        Dim SelectedDataRow As DataGridViewRow = ...
        If SelectedDataRow.Index > 0 Then
            Dim PrevDataRow As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(SelectedDataRow.Index - 1)
            PrevDataRow.Cells("Sequence").Value = SelectedDataRow.Index + 1
            SelectedDataRow.Cells("Sequence").Value = SelectedDataRow.Index                            ' set selected to previous
        End If
```

The moving down is similar, just the condition takes into account a limit of number of rows.

While this worked for me in similar scenario, I usually don't use binding in such scenarios, I use a DataTable as a data mediator.

Comment: Your answer works. but i had to change `PrevDataRow.Cells("Sequence").Value = SelectedDataRow.Index + 1;
            SelectedDataRow.Cells("Sequence").Value = SelectedDataRow.Index; ` to the following:

`PrevDataRow.Cells("Sequence").Value = SelectedDataRow.Index;
 SelectedDataRow.Cells("Sequence").Value = SelectedDataRow.Index+1;`

Comment: Sorry for that, the former is for row numbering starting with 0. Glad it helped a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Up

```
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
    {
        DataGridViewRow Row = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
        if (Row.Index > 0)
        {
            var Index = Row.Index;
            var OldRow = (DataGridViewRow)Row.Clone();
            for (int i = 0; i < OldRow.Cells.Count; i++)
                OldRow.Cells[i].Value = Row.Cells[i].Value;
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(Index);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(Index-1, OldRow);
        }
    }
```

Down

```
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
    {           
        DataGridViewRow Row = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
        if (Row.Index < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1)
        {     
            var Index = Row.Index;
            var OldRow = (DataGridViewRow)Row.Clone();
            for (int i = 0; i < OldRow.Cells.Count; i++)
                OldRow.Cells[i].Value = Row.Cells[i].Value;
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(Index);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(Index + 1, OldRow);
        }
    }
```